# Unexpected result for the Intersection of touching polygons

Tags: intersection, shapely, topology, matplotlib

I have two touching Polygons (two neighbouring counties) and there intersection is a `MultiLineString`, where:

```
len(list(counties["King's Co."].intersection(counties["Queen's Co."]).geoms))  
list(counties["King's Co."].intersection(counties["Queen's Co."]).geoms )[0]  
list(counties["King's Co."].intersection(counties["Queen's Co."]).geoms )[1]
```

gives:

```
924
LINESTRING (-7.1060859 53.1680546, -7.1061766 53.1678101)
LINESTRING (-7.1061766 53.1678101, -7.1072205 53.1666679)
```

I would have expected instead:

```
len(list(counties["King's Co."].intersection(counties["Queen's Co."]).geoms))
len(list(counties["King's Co."].intersection(counties["Queen's Co."]).geoms)[0])
```

to give:

```
1
924
```

why is intersection giving the result like this? I wish to simplify the borders between a set of bordering counties by reducing the number of points, while at the same time preserving topology.

Answer (score 3):

In your case;

- `mls = a.intersection(b)` returns `MultiLineString`.
- `len(mls)`gives you lines' count in `mls`.
- `gs = mls.geoms`returns `GeometrySequence`and `len(gs)` equals `len(mls)`.

So, `len(mls) = len(mls.geoms) = len(list(mls)) = len(list(mls.geoms))`. 
More specifically, it's all about `__len__()` special class method definition.

Note that `len(list(mls))` equals `len(list(mls.geoms))`, however, `list(mls)==list(mls.geoms)` returns `False`(but, of course, lines in the lists have similar geometry)

Comment: But why do I get these 2 point LINESTRINGs? I would like a LINESTRING containing all the boarding points, presuming the counties have a single border with each other.

Comment: There is probably a small gap between them or the points that you think are overlapping in the two counties' polygon are not actually overlapping.